# Incorrect syntax near a keyword in my query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

When i run my query in this method i get the following error:

Got an exception! 
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

NOTE that my courseNr is a VARCHAR in the DB.

I've tried to run the query in MSSQL and it works but not in java.

```
public ArrayList<Student> getAssignedStudents(Course course){
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Student.pnr, Student.namn, Registrering.betyg FROM Registrering INNER JOIN Student ON Registrering.pnr = Student.pnr WHERE betyg != NULL AND kursnr = '" + course.getCourseNr() + "';");

        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while (rset.next()) {

            String pnr = rset.getString("pnr");
            String name = rset.getString("namn");
            String grade = rset.getString("betyg");

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setName(name);
            student.setPnr(pnr);
            student.setGrade(grade);

            studentList.add(student);

        }
        return studentList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think you need a `;` at the end. Also, what is `course.getCourseNr()` producing?

Comment: The `;` cannot be the problem here.

Comment: exactly `;` not a problem query will become `SELECT Student.pnr, Student.namn, Registrering.betyg 
FROM Registrering INNER JOIN Student ON Registrering.pnr = Student.pnr 
WHERE betyg != NULL AND kursnr = 'values';`

Comment: Use IS NOT NULL instead of != NULL

Comment: Ive even tried entering a manual CourseNr but i get the same error, i also tried IS NOT NULL but still get the same error:

Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: You may want to post the error after all.

Comment: post the stack trace and query produced

Comment: Did you try to remove the `;`?

Comment: I can't remove the ';' sign because then the query won't work at all.

Comment: Are you using the right JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `(betyg is not NULL)` instead of what you're doing.
Also, make sure the value of `course.getCourseNr()` does not contain an apostrophe (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

It might be your kursnr is an INT field in you db. If so you should remove the single quotes ' and ' and hopefully you'll be good to go

Comment: My kursnr is a VARCHAR not an int